# NextJS10: i18n routing for "vi" language code doesn't applied

Tags: internationalization, next.js, i18next

I'm using latest version of nextjs with i18n config in next.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en", "vi"],
    defaultLocale: "vi",
  },
};
```

This should make "vi" (Vietnamese) as default language but seem the routing keeps redirect to /en
The  tag always has lang="en" as well

Is it because vi is not supported or I need to config something else? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I don't think adding the i18n config into next.config.js is correct, as next.config.js is mostly for webpack settings. Instead, you will need to add i18n related code into you `_app.js`

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your `Accept-Language` header which sent by your browser. Check the browser's language setting and chaning it into Vietnamese and it would be fine.